# I'm not sure why myst() works this way as a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

```java
public class Recur2 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        myst(4);
    }
        
    public static void myst(int a) {
        if (a != 0) {
            System.out.println("Before: " + a);
            myst(a-1);
            System.out.println("After : " + a);
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be:

```
Before: 4
Before: 3
Before: 2
Before: 1
After: 1
After: 2
After: 3
After: 4
```

But I'm not completely positive on why this works this way. What does the `myst(a-1)` accomplish in the middle of the code, and why does it go in ascending order afterward?

Answer (score 0):

> *But I'm not completely positive on why this works this way.*

It is a simple example of recursion in Java code.  It works this way ... because this is how recursion works.

Recursion happens when a method calls itself.

---

> *What does the `myst(a-1)` accomplish in the middle of the code*

That is the recursion.  That is `myst` calling itself.

You will notice that `myst` is calling itself with an argument that is *one less* than the argument it was called with.  So what happens is:

- `myst(4)` calls `myst(3)`
- `myst(3)` calls `myst(2)`
- `myst(2)` calls `myst(1)`
- `myst(1)` calls `myst(0)`
- `myst(0)` doesn't recurse ... because `a != 0` is not true!

---

> *... and why does it go in ascending order afterward?*

Look where the print statements are.  There is one print "on the way down" and another "on the way back up".  And look at the *expression* that each is printing.  It is `a` ... the *local* parameter ... for *this* call.

If it is still not clicking for you, think of a real world analogy.  For example:

> Imagine you in a room with a step ladder.  Imagine that you have
> climbed to rung 4 of a step ladder.  Your plan is to go the bottom of
> the latter and then back up to 4.  You have a couple of rules.
>
> - Before you step down, you shout out `"BEFORE"` and then the current rung number.
> - After you step back up, you shout out `"AFTER"` and then the current rung number.
>
> Q: What does someone in the next room hear?
>
> A: `"BEFORE 4"` pause, `"BEFORE 3"` pause, `"BEFORE 2"` pause, `"BEFORE 1"` pause, `"AFTER 1"` pause, `"AFTER 2"` pause, `"AFTER 3"` pause, `"AFTER 4"`.

Comment: So myst(4) prints Before: 4, myst(3) prints Before: 3, myst(2) prints Before: 2, and myst(1) prints Before: 1. But then when it hits 0, it just goes back up because that's what recursion is?

Answer (score -1):

This short snippet illustrates how does the concept of recursive function works.

The mist() function does not anything particular apart from calling itself recursively, this is the whole point.

Before and After prints help you understand the order of operations, first recursion goes deeper and deeper, and then it go back-up again (and thus this ascending order).

If this is still not clear, read some online articles of recursion in general - it should help.